# decodeByteArray returns null

Tags: java, android

I read drawable and save it to database. Further I read from database but get null.
Could you please help me?

Here is how I write to database:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageResult.getDrawable();
Bitmap data = drawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
data.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

db = dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("data", stream.toByteArray());

db.insert("table", null, cv);
```

Here is how I read from database:

```
db = dbHelp.getReadableDatabase();
String getProjects = "select data from table where id = (select max(id) from table);";
Cursor cu = db.rawQuery(getProjects, null);
cu.moveToFirst();
data = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(cu.getBlob(0), 0, cu.getBlob(0).length); //here is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Bitmap getImage(){

    String qu = "select data from table where id = (select max(id) from table)" ;
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(qu, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()){
        byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);
        cur.close();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
    }
    if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
        cur.close();
    }       

    return null ;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageResult.getDrawable();
Bitmap data = drawable.getBitmap();

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
data.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);

db = dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("data", stream.toByteArray());

db.insert("table", null, cv);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get error Window is full. Requested allocation at row byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);

Comment: I get error Window is full. Requested allocation at row byte[] imgByte = cur.getBlob(0);

Comment: please Compress your bitmab on save, i have updated code

Comment: while compressing with 60 do i lose quality of bitmap?